# PDO Maximum Execution Time

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a bit of problem with getting information from database.
At the moment when I'm trying to use a method which works with db,I get maximum execution time exceeded error which I didn't get before.
Here's my database code.I get the error on line 68 which is the execute() method

```
        <?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "ff");
    define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");


    class Database{
        private $host      = DB_HOST;
        private $user      = DB_USER;
        private $pass      = DB_PASS;
        private $dbname    = DB_NAME;
        public $query;
        public $result;
        private $con;
        private $error;

        public function __construct(){
            // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
            // Set options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            // Create a new PDO instanace
            try{
                $this->con = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
            }
            // Catch any errors
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


        public function query($query){

        $this->result = $this->con->prepare($query);    


        }



        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->result->bindParam($param,$value,$type);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
    return $this->result->execute();
    }   

    public function rowCount()
    {
    return $this->result->rowCount();
    }

    public function fetch_assoc($result){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }



    }

    $db = new Database();



    ?>
```

Comment: What's the actual query you're trying to execute?

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this class, I'd just ditch it and learn how to properly use PDO if I were you (re-use prepared statements, don't use persistent connections and _please_ don't use global constants to initialize DB properties). Check [this code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29394/16133) on why every simplistic PDO wrapper is essentially flawed